# JavaScript-How to check for a value from a Json array having multiple nodes and arrays?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data that is in the below format.
I need to get the store name corresponding to the one which has specialDeal as true in "Non Veg".
(NOTE: Only one of the stores will have specialDeal as true)
How will i retrieve it. Please help.
thanks in advance .. Please help me as i am just learning Java.

```
    {"Food":
      {
       "Veg":
        {
            "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"", 
            "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
            "FundDetails":[
                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
            ]
         },
       "Non Veg":
            {
            "chicken":
                    [
                    {
                            "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
                            "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
                            "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
                            "FundDetails":[
                                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
                                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
                            ]
         },
         {
                            "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
                            "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
                            "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
                            "FundDetails":[
                                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
                                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
                            ]
         }
        ],
            "fish":
                    [
                    {
                            "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
                            "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
                            "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
                            "FundDetails":[
                                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
                                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                            "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
                            "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
                            "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
                            "FundDetails":[
                                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""},
                                    {"status":"", "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""}
                            ]
                    }
                    ],
            "egg":
                    [
                    {
                            "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
                            "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
                            "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
                            "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""
                    },
                    {
                            "amtSpent":"", "shortDesc":"", "longDesc":"", "excTxt":"",
                            "discntType":"", "Store":"", "StoreType":"", "Fund":"",
                            "specialDeal":"", "promoStatus":"",
                            "discntVal":"", "FundVal":"", "FundBal":""
                    }
                             ]
            },
    "isMember":"Y",
    "orderId":""
}
```

}

Comment: Java or JavaScript? You tagged both, but they're very different things (they say, "Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet").

Comment: Since this is apparently about Java, removed the javascript / jQuery tags.

Comment: @JohnJohny why did you add the javascript tag back, and removed java? I reversed that. Your discussion with Alex below makes it clear you're talking about java, not javascript.

Comment: i need a javascript explanation only. Just thought of learning a new way when alex helped

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use JSONPath for this, using any Java implementation, for example this one: [json-path](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/)

```
List<Object> objectsHavingSpecialDeal = JsonPath.read(json, "$..*[?(@.specialDeal == 'true')]");
// iterate over that list to get the `Store` field value
for (Object o: objectsHavingSpecialDeal) {
    Map<String, String> fields = (Map<String, String>)o;
    System.out.println("Store: " + fields.get("Store"));
}
```

Comment: Just a note (for the OP): that is Java, not JavaScript. Did you figure out which one you're asking about?

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex.. I would b grateful if u can explain a bit more on how to iterate the list as i am new to Java world

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is there any other way than using JsonPath.? Heard could be done using Hash Map or so. Can u please spend a couple more minutes helping me with this. Sitting with this for a long time nw. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming javascript:

You have a slight inconsistency in your data, concerning vegetables, I'd suggest restructuring it like this:

```
var test = { "Food":
{
    "Veg":
            {
                "vegetables":
                    [
                    {
                        "amtSpent": "", "shortDesc": "", "longDesc": "", "excTxt": "",
                        "discntType": "", "Store": "", "StoreType": "", "Fund": "",
                        "FundDetails": [
                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" },
                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" }
                            ]
                    }]
            },
    "Non Veg":
            {
                "chicken":
                    [
                    {
                        "amtSpent": "", "shortDesc": "", "longDesc": "", "excTxt": "",
                        "discntType": "", "Store": "", "StoreType": "", "Fund": "",
                        "specialDeal": "", "promoStatus": "",
                        "FundDetails": [
                                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" },
                                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        "amtSpent": "", "shortDesc": "", "longDesc": "", "excTxt": "",
                        "discntType": "", "Store": "", "StoreType": "", "Fund": "",
                        "specialDeal": "", "promoStatus": "",
                        "FundDetails": [
                                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" },
                                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" }
                            ]
         }
        ],
                "fish":
                    [
                    {
                        "amtSpent": "", "shortDesc": "", "longDesc": "", "excTxt": "",
                        "discntType": "", "Store": "", "StoreType": "", "Fund": "",
                        "specialDeal": "", "promoStatus": "",
                        "FundDetails": [
                                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" },
                                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        "amtSpent": "", "shortDesc": "", "longDesc": "", "excTxt": "",
                        "discntType": "", "Store": "", "StoreType": "", "Fund": "",
                        "specialDeal": "", "promoStatus": "",
                        "FundDetails": [
                                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" },
                                    { "status": "", "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": "" }
                            ]
                    }
                    ],
                "egg":
                    [
                    {
                        "amtSpent": "", "shortDesc": "", "longDesc": "", "excTxt": "",
                        "discntType": "", "Store": "", "StoreType": "", "Fund": "",
                        "specialDeal": "", "promoStatus": "",
                        "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "amtSpent": "", "shortDesc": "", "longDesc": "", "excTxt": "",
                        "discntType": "", "Store": "", "StoreType": "", "Fund": "",
                        "specialDeal": "", "promoStatus": "",
                        "discntVal": "", "FundVal": "", "FundBal": ""
                    }
                             ]
            },
    "isMember": "Y",
    "orderId": ""
}
}
```

Then, you can get all objects with a `specialDeal` property, like this:

```
for (key in test.Food) {
    if (test.Food.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var f = test.Food[key];
        for (cat in f) {
            if (f.hasOwnProperty(cat)) {
                for (prop in f[cat]) {
                    if (f[cat].hasOwnProperty(prop) && f[cat][prop].specialDeal != undefined) {
                        console.log(f[cat][prop].specialDeal, f[cat][prop], "Category: " + cat + ", Index: " + prop)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It ain't pretty, but it works.

What I'm doing here is that I'm looping through the object.
`for (key in test.Food) {}` finds all keys in `test.Food`, those being:

```
Veg
Non Veg
isMember
orderId
```

You can then get the sub-object using `test.Food[key]`, and loop through that object again.
Further down the loop, I'm testing if the object has a `specialDeal` property. If that's the case, I log it.

The problem with objects is that, if you want to search through them for objects having a certain value, the object has to have a regular formatting. that's why I added a bject to `"Veg"`.

Comment: @ Cerbrus Thanks a lot cerbrus. But i am finding it a bit tough to understand. wot is dat we need to give in for conditions exactly. can u help me with that seeing the question. i mean i would b so grateful if u can answer it exactly like my question. i meant the exact code for my question.. Please

Comment: @JohnJohny: Edited in some info.